# .htaccess code to redirect dynamic links to new dynamic links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have redesigned my site

Previous link sample is:

```
mydomain.com?index.php?mo=blog&srno=62#
```

New link will be:

```
mydomain.com?blog-post.php?srno=62
```

Here `srno` can be any digit from `1` to `62` .

How can I redirect user coming with previous link to new link with .htaccess ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?mo=blog&(srno=\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog-post.php?%1 [L,R=301]
```